# Select all MySQL data, count records by month, year not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a database table with a list of IP addresses each with a `datetime` column, which in basic is something like this example:

```
ip_address    | date_first_viewed
192.122.42.2    2015-12-23 14:03:10
183.123.13.4    2015-12-23 02:11:10
193.311.31.6    2015-11-10 12:29:00
```

I am trying to select, count and group the data according to Month, Year so it would show as:

```
(2015, 12)  2
(2015, 11)  1
```

Here is my current query I am using although this isn't returning any dates whatsoever?

```
$sql8 = "SELECT COUNT(ip_address) as count, EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date_first_viewed) as date
         FROM `all_website_stats`
         GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date_first_viewed)";
```

Comment: Your SQL appears to work.  I created a duplicate table and ran that query against it successfully.  Possibly the issue is in your PHP instead?  Verify that it runs properly against your database by executing the query outside of your code.  My preference is to execute the query from the command line before writing it into my code.

Comment: Another note, I believe `count` and `date` are both reserved words.  It doesn't appear to be causing any issues in my testing, but I would highly recommend escaping those words with backticks, or altering them slightly to no longer be reserved words.  Change count to ip_count or whatever.

Comment: I've adjusted my code to your advice and it is now returning the data but only as `201512` is there a way to separate this date to `2015, 12` using my SQL or would that have to be done manually?

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT('(', YEAR(date_first_viewed), ', ', MONTH(date_first_viewed), ')') FROM table;`

Comment: I reformulated my comments into one answer.  Feel free to accept it, if it provided all of the information you needed.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL looks good.  Just escape the reserved words `count` and `date` with backticks to avoid issues.  To get the date in the format you want, you might try this query, which just concatenates the additional characters you want for formatting:

`SELECT CONCAT('(', YEAR(date_first_viewed), ', ', MONTH(date_first_viewed), ')') FROM table;`

So for your example:

```
SELECT COUNT(ip_address) as `count`, CONCAT('(', YEAR(date_first_viewed), ', ', MONTH(date_first_viewed), ')') as `date`
     FROM `all_website_stats` GROUP BY CONCAT('(', YEAR(date_first_viewed), ', ', MONTH(date_first_viewed), ')')";
```

should do it!